# Rails Heroku Deployment 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production-environment

I deployed with Heroku and files transferred fine, but the app isn't working. I think it has something to do with production database but I can't seem to figure out how to solve it. My app works fine under development on my machine. I ran some rake db commands on heroku such as

$ heroku rake db:reset --trace

and I got

rake aborted!
no such file to load -- faker
/app/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:1:in `require'
/app/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:1
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in`load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `load_tasks'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in`each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `load_tasks'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:141:in`load_tasks'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in`method_missing'
/app/Rakefile:7
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in`raw_load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in`standard_exception_handling'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in`run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in`run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/rake:19
(in /app)

then, I ran
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate --trace

and got

** Invoke db:migrate (first_time) 
** Invoke environment (first_time) 
** Execute environment 
** Execute db:migrate 
== CreateUsers: migrating ==================================================== 
-- create_table(:users) 
-> 0.0012s 
== CreateUsers: migrated (0.0013s) ===========================================

== AddEmailUniquenessIndex: migrating ======================================== 
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true}) 
-> 0.0008s 
== AddEmailUniquenessIndex: migrated (0.0009s) ===============================

== AddPasswordToUsers: migrating ============================================= 
-- add_column(:users, :encrypted_password, :string) 
-> 0.0352s 
== AddPasswordToUsers: migrated (0.0353s) ====================================

== AddSaltToUsers: migrating ================================================= 
-- add_column(:users, :salt, :string) 
-> 0.0005s 
== AddSaltToUsers: migrated (0.0006s) ========================================

== AddAdminToUsers: migrating ================================================ 
-- add_column(:users, :admin, :boolean, {:default=>false}) 
-> 0.0092s 
== AddAdminToUsers: migrated (0.0093s) =======================================

== CreateMicroposts: migrating =============================================== 
-- create_table(:microposts) 
-> 0.0009s 
== CreateMicroposts: migrated (0.0010s) ======================================

== CreateRelationships: migrating ============================================ 
-- create_table(:relationships) 
-> 0.0009s 
-- add_index(:relationships, :follower_id) 
-> 0.0004s 
-- add_index(:relationships, :followed_id) 
-> 0.0004s 
== CreateRelationships: migrated (0.0019s) ===================================

== CreateCarts: migrating ==================================================== 
-- create_table(:carts) 
-> 0.0014s 
== CreateCarts: migrated (0.0015s) ===========================================

== CreateLineItems: migrating ================================================ 
-- create_table(:line_items) 
-> 0.0010s 
== CreateLineItems: migrated (0.0010s) =======================================

== AddQuantityToLineItem: migrating ========================================== 
-- add_column(:line_items, :quantity, :integer, {:default=>1}) 
-> 0.0006s 
== AddQuantityToLineItem: migrated (0.0007s) =================================

== CombineItemsInCart: migrating ============================================= 
== CombineItemsInCart: migrated (0.0134s) ====================================

== CreateOrders: migrating =================================================== 
-- create_table(:orders) 
-> 0.0011s 
== CreateOrders: migrated (0.0012s) ==========================================

== AddOrderIdToLineItem: migrating =========================================== 
-- add_column(:line_items, :order_id, :integer) 
-> 0.0005s 
== AddOrderIdToLineItem: migrated (0.0005s) ==================================

== AddUsernameToUsers: migrating ============================================= 
-- add_column(:users, :username, :string) 
-> 0.0005s 
== AddUsernameToUsers: migrated (0.0006s) ====================================

== AddUsernameUniquenessIndex: migrating ===================================== 
-- add_index(:users, :username, {:unique=>true}) 
-> 0.0012s 
== AddUsernameUniquenessIndex: migrated (0.0014s) ============================

== CreateStores: migrating =================================================== 
-- create_table(:stores) 
-> 0.0010s 
== CreateStores: migrated (0.0011s) ==========================================

== AddPasswordToStores: migrating ============================================ 
-- add_column(:stores, :encrypted_password, :string) 
-> 0.0007s 
== AddPasswordToStores: migrated (0.0008s) ===================================

== AddUsernameToStores: migrating ============================================ 
-- add_column(:stores, :username, :string) 
-> 0.0006s 
== AddUsernameToStores: migrated (0.0007s) ===================================

== AddSaltToStores: migrating ================================================ 
-- add_column(:stores, :salt, :string) 
-> 0.0009s 
== AddSaltToStores: migrated (0.0010s) =======================================

== AddAdminToStores: migrating =============================================== 
-- add_column(:stores, :admin, :boolean, {:default=>false}) 
-> 0.0008s 
== AddAdminToStores: migrated (0.0009s) ======================================

== RemoveNameFromOrders: migrating =========================================== 
-- remove_column(:orders, :name) 
-> 0.0062s 
== RemoveNameFromOrders: migrated (0.0063s) ==================================

== AddFirstNameToOrders: migrating =========================================== 
-- add_column(:orders, :first_name, :string) 
-> 0.0005s 
== AddFirstNameToOrders: migrated (0.0006s) ==================================

== AddLastNameToOrders: migrating ============================================ 
-- add_column(:orders, :last_name, :string) 
-> 0.0005s 
== AddLastNameToOrders: migrated (0.0006s) ===================================

== AddAddress1ToOrders: migrating ============================================ 
-- add_column(:orders, :address1, :text) 
-> 0.0006s 
== AddAddress1ToOrders: migrated (0.0007s) ===================================

== AddCardExpiresOnToOrders: migrating ======================================= 
-- add_column(:orders, :card_expires_on, :date) 
-> 0.0005s 
== AddCardExpiresOnToOrders: migrated (0.0006s) ==============================

== AddBillingidToUsers: migrating ============================================ 
-- add_column(:users, :billing_id, :string) 
-> 0.0005s 
== AddBillingidToUsers: migrated (0.0006s) ===================================

== RemoveNameFromStores: migrating =========================================== 
-- remove_column(:stores, :name) 
-> 0.0093s 
== RemoveNameFromStores: migrated (0.0094s) ==================================

== RemoveSaltFromStores: migrating =========================================== 
-- remove_column(:stores, :salt) 
-> 0.0079s 
== RemoveSaltFromStores: migrated (0.0080s) ==================================

== RemoveAdminFromStores: migrating ========================================== 
-- remove_column(:stores, :admin) 
-> 0.0065s 
== RemoveAdminFromStores: migrated (0.0066s) =================================

== RemoveUsernameFromStores: migrating ======================================= 
-- remove_column(:stores, :username) 
-> 0.0063s 
== RemoveUsernameFromStores: migrated (0.0065s) ==============================

== AddStorenameToStores: migrating =========================================== 
-- add_column(:stores, :store_name, :string) 
-> 0.0006s 
== AddStorenameToStores: migrated (0.0007s) ==================================

== RemoveEncryptedPasswordFromStores: migrating ============================== 
-- remove_column(:stores, :encrypted_password) 
-> 0.0060s 
== RemoveEncryptedPasswordFromStores: migrated (0.0061s) =====================

== AddUserIdToStores: migrating ============================================== 
-- add_column(:stores, :user_id, :integer) 
rake aborted! 
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "stores" ADD "user_id" integer

The error:

== AddUserIdToStores: migrating ============================================== 
-- add_column(:stores, :user_id, :integer) 
rake aborted! 
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "stores" ADD "user_id" integer

I don't get this because I didn't add this column twice. I messed around with migration files, does that have anything to do with this? Thanks. I really hope somebody can help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migrations tend to break when you run enough of them in a row. If you are creating your db from scratch use:

```
heroku db:schema:load
```

Generally I tend to get something reasonable going in my dev database and simply use

```
heroku db:push
```

If you are not familiar with it, it will copy both schema and data from your dev db to your app db on heroku. Either one of those might be a reasonable workaround for your issue.
I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you so much for the help! I installed taps and ran heroku db:push and it worked like magic. I actually have a question though about migrations because I think this might be the reason why I had trouble. I actually deleted some files under migration folder and changed names around as well. Do you think that has anything to do with this? I assumed that db gets copied and migration files were irrelevant in deploying into heroku. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Your schema.rb is really the last word on your db schema. Migrations are supposed to get your db from one consistent state to another (and back if necessary). In theory you can run them from the beginning and get a working db but its common for migrations to reference things that other migrations have deleted or will delete. Going back and editing migrations usually makes it more likely that that will happen. I think that is what was happening to you. Keep your migrations, but recognize their limits.